# RSS Feed in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I have to develop RSS Feed in asp.net. Events will be logged as text along with the more set of fields. This table will be published as an RSS feed to be loaded in Outlook. I have no idea how to develop this though I have few queries:

1. My understanding after reading on RSS Feed is that it has to be in specific format. Is it?
2. I have to generate different types of messages. Do I need to create different-different RSS feed?
3. How RSS feed will be loaded in Outlook? I know user need to configure it in outlook though How will it load new event in outlook automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate rss feeds using SyndicationFeed class in dotnet. It is available in the system.Servicemodel.Syndication namespace. Look up on msdn for syndication feed and you find a sample for generating both rss 2.0 and atom 1.0 feeds. 
To answer your questions:
1. Yes feeds need to be in rss or atom formats. Dotnet supports feed generation in both atom and rss. You essentially pick the formatter you want and serialize the object that contains the data for the feed. 
2. Typically there is one feed which contains several feed items. Example: google news has an rss feed. This is a single feed and each news item is a feed item. 
3. Outlook 2007 has an entry for rss feeds in  inbox. Right-click gives you an option to add a new feed where you will enter the url for the feed. 
Since you are new to rss i suggest you load certain rss feeds in a browser. In the browser view tge source of the page and you will see the xml containing the feed. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for late revert. If I create a aspx page (which generate different feed based on paramater) which generate XML per RSS standard. If any user, add that link to his/her outlook, will they receive feed automatically?

Comment: The url for the feed should point to an xml page not aspx. Rss readers and browsers understand this xml format. All you need to do is to use the syndication feed classes,  add your feeds and write the feed xml string to a file.  It is as simple as that. Make sure you have set the right mime settings on the website to serve xml pages.

Comment: Oh  I see. So I have to rewrite xml file with new contents (replacing older onces) every time? What if someone miss earlier post?

Comment: That depends on how you add the feeds. You can choose to add new feed items or update existing feeds. How to purge old feed items depends in the application  to some extent and the expected usage. See existing feeds like google news or a plethora of others that are available to see how they do it.

Comment: Ok. Last.. can I allow user to add paramter (example.com/feed.xml?client=disney) to let user filter out feed in outlook?

Comment: That i am not sure. But you can definitely publish different feeds for each category and have separate urls.